# How to resolve unmet dependencies to install libreoffice-*

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

I am use the original /etc/apt/sources.list

I do not wanted to install ppa/libreoffice, since a lot of such hang up GUI.

I have try these steps and does not work.

```
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -f install libreoffice-calc libreoffice-writer libreoffice-impress
```

And this is what package I wants to install it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libreoffice-calc libreoffice-writer libreoffice-impress 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: libreoffice-base-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu5.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu5.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-impress : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu5.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libreoffice-draw (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu5.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-writer : Depends: libreoffice-base-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu5.1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu5.1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

libreoffice is an office suite, individual programs have interdependency on back ends. try `sudo apt-get install libreoffice` to get the entire suite